# Cannot copy one textbox value to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to copy one textbox value to another textbox but I'm not getting the result. Here's what I've done so far:

JQUERY

```
function BindQuantity(id, customqty) {
    $(id).keyup(function () {
        var qty = $(id).val();
        $(customqty).val(qty);
    })
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    BindQuantity("input:text[id^='Quantity'" + "]",
                "input:text[id^='CustomQuantity'" + "]");
})
```

HTML

```
<input type="number" name="abcd" id="Quantity" style="width:130px;" />
<input id="CustomQuantity" type="text" value="" />
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/M34mk/

I want to bind the `Quantity` textbox value to the `CustomQuantity` Textbox on keyup event.

Comment: what happens when you call your method like this? BindQuantity("#Quantity", "#CustomQuantity");

Comment: it worked correctly when i call the method like u mentioned, but i have dynamic generated textboxes so that's why i'm using other approach, please guide me i want to use it on every dynamic textbox

Comment: @Usama Your jsfiddle worked fine for me once I added jQuery to it

Comment: I will post an answer with an approach

Comment: okay thanks i'm waiting and i also want to bind them each time with new value with dynamic textboxes

Comment: @neiha the CustomQuantity textbox work only when i change type to text but not working on type "Number"

Comment: @xd6_ the CustomQuantity textbox work only when i change type to text but not working on type "Number"

Comment: oh so you generate dinamically your textboxes?

Comment: @neiha yes this is the main issue

Comment: @Usama: Your code working fine after including the Jquery reference. See http://jsfiddle.net/M34mk/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is closer to what you need

```
<input type="text" name="abcd" id="Quantity3" style="width:130px;" class="defaultQuantity"/>
<input id="CustomQuantity3" type="number" value="" class="customQuantity" />
<br/>

<input type="text" name="abcd" id="Quantity4" style="width:130px;" class="defaultQuantity"/>
<input id="CustomQuantity4" type="number" value="" class="customQuantity" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="abcd" id="Quantity5" style="width:130px;" class="defaultQuantity"/>
<input id="CustomQuantity5" type="number" value="" class="customQuantity" />


function BindQuantity(id, customqty) {
 $(id).keyup(function () {
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var customBoxId="#Custom"+$(this).attr("id");
    $(customBoxId).val(qty);
 })
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 BindQuantity(".defaultQuantity"); 
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M34mk/3/

Comment: i'm changing the ID when new dynamic textbox created how can i do this here? and another problem is the CustomQuantity textbox work only when i change type to text but not working on type "Number"

Comment: that's why i'm using the class selector instead of the ID. I think it would be easier if you update your jsfiddle with your entire case =)

Comment: thanks alot i'm using "("input:text[id^='Quantity']").live("keyup", null, function () {" it only run when i press two key, is there any way to run this on a single key up or key press?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine

```
function BindQuantity(id, customqty) {
$('body').on('keyup' , id , function(){
    var qty = $(id).val();
    $(customqty).val(qty);        
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
BindQuantity("input:text[id^='Quantity'" + "]",
            "input:text[id^='CustomQuantity'" + "]");
});
```

you can replace 'Quantity' , 'CustomQuantity' with the dynamically generated IDs

Answer (score 0):

You have used the textbox ID  in an incorrect format

try like this

```
     var qty = $(id).val();
     $("#customqty").val(qty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$('#Quantity')[0].onkeyup = function() {
          $('#CustomQuantity')[0].value= $('#Quantity').val()
}
```